# I am stuck with $this error using php classes

Tags: php, class, this

I am new to working with php classes, so bear with me.

I am getting this error:

"Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in..."

I am attempting to call a function inside the same class.  I am able to call the same function from another class so I am confused.

Here is the snippet from the class:

```
    public function listLocations() {

    // get all the locations
    $listLocations = self::getLocations();

    echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div><h2>Locations Class</h2></div>';

    foreach ($listLocations as $data) {

        echo 'Location - '.$data->location.'<br>';

    }

}


public function getLocations(){

    $Locations = $this->db->get_results("select location_id, location FROM {$this->soups_locations_db}");

    return $Locations;

}
```

This is inside the Class Foo_Locations

I am calling this same function using this snippet from another class.  I get the results that I am looking for without error so I am confused.

```
$myLocations = count(Foo_Locations::getLocations());
```

The error is pointing to this line in the Foo_Locations Class

```
    $Locations = $this->db->get_results("select location_id, location FROM {$this->soups_locations_db}");
```

But I think its related to this line:

```
$listLocations = self::getLocations();
```

This community's help is always greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `$this->getLocations();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling getLocations statically using self::getLocations();

`$this->getLocations()` allows you to use the instantiated class to call getLocations().